# Bootstrap Standard Error vs Standard Error from sample

Tags: inference, mean, bootstrap, standard-error, sample

For doing inference of a population parameter from a sample, under which examples is better to calculate the standard error using bootstrap distribution of the mean than directly using the standard error of the sample?

Let's take the *mean of income* as an example:

1. I can take a sample and calculate the *income mean*, and from the sample I can calculate the standard error using *sample_standard_deviation/square_root(n)*.
2. I can treat my sample as the "population", and apply the bootstrap, and thus create the distribution of the mean and infer the standard error.

Which are some example on using one over the other?

Comment: Did you mean "standard deviation over square root sample size" in your first bullet?

Comment: Yep. Correcting @DemetriPananos

Comment: and by "doing inference", do you mean something specifically?  Would you be using the standard errors in a confidence interval, for example?

Comment: How exactly do you propose applying the bootstrap?  The SE of the mean will always be directly proportional to the SD of the bootstrap distribution of the mean, anyway.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Yes. Type: what is the confidence interval for the mean of the population given this sample? The easiest questions.

Comment: @whuber They will be similar, but the question is: on which example do you use one over another?

Comment: Some examples here: https://thestatsgeek.com/2013/07/02/the-miracle-of-the-bootstrap/#:~:text=The%20idea%20of%20the%20bootstrap,took%20samples%20from%20the%20population.

Comment: @marz if you're going to use them in a confidence interval, why not just compute a bootstrap confidence interval?

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to ask since I don't have the answer: Why & where use the bootstrap standard error to calculate the confidence interval, instead of directly calculating the standard error from the sample standard deviation and the construct the confidence interval @DemetriPananos

Comment: @marz There are lots of variations for bootstrapped confidence intervals, many of which just use the bootstrap samples directly rather than an estimate of the standard error.  I would suggest you use either bias corrected boot strap confidence intervals or bootstrapped t intervals to start.  Both are described in [this](https://hastie.su.domains/CASI_files/PDF/casi.pdf) book in chapter 11.

Comment: Thank you! On the other side, on which cases/assumptions you are safe from calculation your SE directly from the sample using *sample_standard_deviation/square_root(n)* instead of using a bootstrap method? @DemetriPananos